# How are first tier tribunal case reference numbers formulated?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-citation, tribunal, tribunal-procedure

Here is an example of a first tier tribunal case reference number: BIR/00CN/LVE/2012/0001.

The case being Scriven & ors v Calthorpe Estates & ors.

In the reference, the first section appears to be Birmingham, apparently the tribunal’s geographic division in which it was heard, while the penultimate section appears to be a year.

What is represented by each of the others?

Comment: I can't find any relevant Rules or Practice Directions to explain the naming conventions, and the search term *BIR/* on [BAILII](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/lucy_search_1.cgi?query=Bir%2F&results=50&submit=Search&rank=on&callback=on&mask_path=uk%2Fcases%2FUKFTT%2FPC) returns a variety of combinations with no obvious pattern. I'll make some enquiries but it will take some time to get an answer; if at all.

Comment: @Rick - all the Birmingham ones seem to start BIR/00CN and then there are three letters which seem to indicate a particular type of FTT Residential Property Tribunal case - I reckon LVT could be the former Local Valuation Tribunal area of work, and LBC looks like Leasehold Breach of Covenant. I can't guess what LVE might be.

Comment: I think 00CN is an ONS code (for Birmingham) fwiw

Comment: @alexg - you can find 00CS, 00FK for Birmingham etc here and some sample references for other regions  https://www.gov.uk/residential-property-tribunal-decisions

Comment: 00FK is Derby, so this element looks like it matches the location of the property in question (as opposed to the BIR which is where the Property Chamber was meeting)

Comment: https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201213/cmselect/cmcomloc/177/177vw103.htm explains the codes beginning PH (for the third element). Presumably there are similar for other categories of decision.

Comment: @alexg Very astute. I think those two parts (tribunal region and property location as ONS area code) of the puzzle is solved, then. It seems likely that there is a year and a serial number, leaving only the three letter code remaining as mystery. (edit: well, apparently not completely, it seems likely to be the type of action, however we still haven't found a legend to what the codes all mean.)